# Shared hosting High ram and I/o usage. Cpanel solution?

Tags: wordpress, cpanel, shared-hosting

I have a WordPress install with godaddy. Often times I see that the site has high **memory usage** and **i/o usage**.

[image]

I am not an expert when it comes to web servers but I do get by with some level of knowledge.

I have not installed any new plugins that might have caused this.

I have the following questions:

1. Is there a way I can monitor what is consuming memory and i/o with cpanel?
2. I do have **google authenticator** plugin installed that will block more than three failed password attempts. Is the plugin sufficient in preventing brute force attacks?

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that not good for you.This good tips for you. `Cloudflare`that's good for your (free or premium), That will be reduce your problems (*Free SSL, Improve speed, Security, manage DNS, Caching (will reduce your problem), Blacklist/ Whitelist IP, etc*) .

**and other tips is:**

Excessive load times can harm your website in more ways than one. There are quite a few ways to improve your site’s speed but caching has the greatest impact.

With the above in mind, going to evaluate the performance of the top five caching solutions for WordPress to help you determine which one is truly the best (not just the fastest).

**Here’s the lineup: `WP Rocket, W3 Total Cache, WP Super Cache, WP Fastest Cache, and ZenCache`.**

**The last solutions: Upgrade your hosting**

I hope this help full